# Make a phone number ring for some time using a 56KB modem

Tags: ubuntu, python, serial, modem, telephony

we have an old modem model [US Robotics Sportster Flash](http://www.usr-emea.com/support/s-prod-template.asp?loc=emea&prod=sportster) and we'd need to use it to open a door in our organization, by making a phone call to an internal number (say, `101`).

We are running on an Ubuntu based machine and we are trying to set up a single command to be executed (from command line) to make the phone call.
Such call should be interrupted by the client after a few seconds, in order to avoid a busy line.

We've tried using `minicom` software version `2.5` (the modem is accessible through `/dev/ttyS0` device), executed through the `minicom -s on` command.

It follows our attempt to make the phone call.

```
AT S7=45 S0=0 L1 V1 X4 &c1 E1 Q0
OK
AT
OK
ATD101
NO DIAL TONE
ATDT101
NO DIAL TONE
ATD,101,
DIALING DISABLED
```

Although connections at the physical layer is ok, we are getting the `NO DIAL TONE` error.

In any case, our final attempt would involve a Python script using the `serial` library.

How can we solve that?

Comment: Do you get a dial tone when plugging a normal phone to the phone line the modem is connected to?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, if I receive a phone call on the modem line, I get a `RING` message from `minicom`.

Comment: Have you tried a different model modem to rule out hardware problems?

Comment: You verified that you have dialtone with an old school analog phone, right?

Comment: By the way regarding writing a python script, this is not needed. Unless you want to reinvent the wheel, you can use my [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program to send AT command to a modem from the command line. It is specifically written to cover use cases like this.